# SharePoint 2013 Calculated Column- Evaluate 3 other columns and return non-null value

Tags: sharepoint-2013, formula, calculated-columns

I have three content types on my SharePoint list, each with a calculated value (a number between 0-3) representing the Health of the project for that project type (Health1 is a calculation specific to Project Type 1, Health2 is a calculation specific to Project Type 2, etc.).

Therefore, depending on the Content Type of the list item, only one of these 3 columns will have a number value between 0-3 and the other 2 will always be null.

I want to create a list-level shared calculated column called simply "Health. The formula for "Health" needs to evaluate Health1, Health2 and Health3 and return the number from whichever is not null. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 0 is a FALSE value

```
=IF( [Health1] , 1 , IF( [Health2] , 2 , IF( [Health3] , 3 , 0 )))
```

Will return 1,2,3 or 0

.

Hey! Its Friday!
Lets add some extra BI fun and add a color indicator for your 0-3 Health level

Create another Calculated Column [HealthStatus]

SET THE DATATYPE TO NUMBER, this makes the HTML work:

Formula:

```
="<div style=""background:"
&CHOOSE( 
    IF( [Health1] , [Health1] , IF( [Health2] , [Health2] , IF( [Health3] , [Health3] , 0 ))) + 1
    ,"none","lightgreen","yellow","indianred")
&";text-align:center;"">Health "
& [Health]
&"</div>"
```

In the CHOOSE formula we add 1 to your 0-3 level to select color 1-4

I used no color for the health=0 value

You can use HTML colornames or CSS values.
See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

Note the use of double-double quotes; so the endresult HTML is like:

```
<DIV style="background:yellow;text-align:center">Health 2</DIV>
```

Again; set the datatype to Number so the Calculated Column is actually processed as HTML
if you want to check the HTML (maybe a typo somewhere) you can set the datatype to Text, this will display the HTML as text in your View.